# How to get only specific fields from Laravel Eloquent API Resource?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am working on an API that will be accessible via a mobile and web app.
I need to send specific fields from the API resource.

I have `ItemResource`

```php
public function toArray($request) {
    return [
        'id'          => $this->id,
        'name'        => $this->name,
        'description' => $this->description,
        'price'       => $this->price,
        'stock'       => $this->stock,
        'reviews'     => $this->reviews, // this is from reviews table
    ];
}
```

My `Item` Model

```php
public function reviews() {
    return $this->hasMany(ItemReview::class);
}
```

My controller code

```php
return ItemResource::collection(Item::all());
```

I get this array

```js
{
    "data": {
        "id": 10,
        "name": "Item Name",
        "description": "Item description",
        "price": 410,
        "stock": "815",
        "reviews": [
            {
                "id": 4,       // I don't want to get this field
                "item_id": 10, // I don't want to get this field
                "user_id": 9,  // I want to show user name instead of user id
                "review": "item review."
            },
            {
                "id": 12,      // I don't want to get this field
                "item_id": 10, // I don't want to get this field
                "user_id": 3,  // I want to show user name instead of user id
                "review": "item review."
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I want to get an array like this

```js
{
    "data": {
        "id": 10,
        "name": "Item Name",
        "description": "Item description",
        "price": 410,
        "stock": "815",
        "reviews": [
            {
                "user_name": 'jhon',  
                "review": "item review."
            },
            {
                "user_name": 'jhon2',  
                "review": "item review."
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I would like to show only specific fields.
How can I implement this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## 1. Only `select` what you need

If you add parentheses after `reviews`, you can return a `Builder` instance, which will allow you to add queries to the relationship.
With this, you can `select` the fields you need.

```php
public function toArray($request) {
    return [
        'id'          => $this->id,
        'name'        => $this->name,
        'description' => $this->description,
        'price'       => $this->price,
        'stock'       => $this->stock,
        'reviews'     => $this->reviews()->select('user_name', 'review')->get(),
    ];
}
```

## 2. Create a `ReviewResource`

You can also create a [resource](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources#resource-collections) for `Review` that returns it's own data.

```php
class ReviewResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'user_name' => $this->user_name,
            'review' => $this->review,
        ];
    }
}
```

```php
class ItemResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request) {
        return [
            'id'          => $this->id,
            'name'        => $this->name,
            'description' => $this->description,
            'price'       => $this->price,
            'stock'       => $this->stock,
            'reviews'     => ReviewResource::collection($this->reviews),
        ];
    }
}
```